# empty DataTable to Json with columns name

Tags: c#, json, datatable, server, json.net

My app is divided in two parts : client and server. 
The server side ask a sql database and store the results in a DataTable. 
Then i use the next function to convert the DataTable to Json to send it to client.

The problem is when there are no results, i get an empty string. 
I would like to get a string which will allow the client side to display an empty datatable **but with column names, i mean with column header !**

Here is the function on the server side to convert datatable to Json:

```
 public string ConvertDataTabletoString(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

And here is the function on client side to convert Json to DataTable back:

```
return (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(clientSoap.dataCommand(command), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: try NewtonSoft dll. string jsonString=string.Empty;
   jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);

Comment: i go with @viveknuna. Try newtonsoft. It's avaiable via NuGet. You could stop using ugly DataTables and make the whole stuff with wonderfull objects and List<T> :) The Newtonsoft Package works well with it.

Comment: @Sebi , i add it an hour ago but i don't really understand how to use it. I get the result from the database in a datatable and then ?

Comment: i mean there is no changes using it, in the "no rows" situation i still get an empty string

Answer (score 2):

In the "no data rows" scenario, your code is serializing an empty dictionary. If you want to have your list of columns you could add a snippet of code like the following to ensure that your rows dictionary isn't empty.

```
    ...
    rows.Add(row);
}
if (rows.Count == 0)
{
    var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, "");
    rows.Add(row);
}
return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

If the client is sending data back to the server you will need to do something to ensure that the server doesn't try to store the empty row as data.

Comment: Thank for response.        row.Add(col.ColumnName, "");

Comment: Thanks for response you wrote         row.Add(col.ColumnName, "");
 do you mean 'rows' ? it doesn't work !

Comment: I did mean rows but I also missed that you were storing a list of name value pairs for your data. I updated my code sample.

Comment: with your edit i now get the column names but i also get an empty row. I am thinking about creating a function on the client side to delete that row after deserialising but its not very clean work :)

Comment: I agree - deleting the empty row on the client is messy. I don't know how much flexibility you have with the client-side representation of your data. You could create a serializable class that contains a list of column names and the row data similar in structure to DataTable. Then always populate the column names and you don't have to worry about special cases where you have no data rows.

Answer (score 2):

I used the response of @Richard and i created a function that check if we returned an empty datatable to delete the new empty row created. It's not 100% nice but its work fine.

On the server side :

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, "");
                rows.Add(row);
                return "empty" + serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
            }
        }
```

On the client side:

```
DataTable JsonToDataTable (string text)
        {
            if(text.Substring(0,5) == "empty")
            {
                text = text.Remove(0, 5);
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, (typeof(DataTable)));
                dt.Rows[0].Delete();
                return dt;
            }
            return (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, (typeof(DataTable)));
        }
```