# Serializing a DataSet with empty data tables loses all column information

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dataset

I tried to serialise a dataset to json.Everything is working fine,but column informations are missing ,if no records.I found some solutions,but none of them are not solving my issue.

I write a stored procedure to retrieve all the table records from MSSQL server and stored into a dataset and then tried serialise into json using NewtonSoft,and then write this into a Json file.

```
DataSet ds_v 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds_v);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "/txt.json", json);
```

I Want the output like follows

```
{
"Table": [],//here iam getting empty table without having column informations.So i want to get the column informations


"Table1": [
{
 }]

}
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110498/empty-datatable-to-json-with-columns-name

Comment: have you checked [Schema Serialization Mode property](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.schemaserializationmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataSet_SchemaSerializationMode)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the datatable's rows count is 0 then add an empty row. then you can see the schema of table after serializing. like this:

```
if (ds_v.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                var row = ds_v.Tables[0].NewRow();
                ds_v.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            }
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds_v);
```

or if you just want to see schema without any modifying of dataset you can use this code

```
var cols = ds_v.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cols, Formatting.Indented);
```