# JsonConvert.SerializeObject Removes Columns From Empty Datatable

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using **JsonConvert.SerializeObject** to serialize DataSets. Occasionally, DataTables within my DataSet don't have any rows, but the DataTable does have columns. When I serialize the DataSet if a DataTable doesn't have any rows all of the columns get removed from the DataTable.

I'm wondering if theres a way for me to serialize the DataSet and not lose the columns on DataTables without rows.

Here is an example to demonstrate my issue. Here I create a DataTable and add two columns to it. Then I add the DataTable to a DataSet and serialize the DataSet:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
col1.DataType = typeof(Int32);
col1.ColumnName = "Id";
dt.Columns.Add(col1);

DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn();
col2.DataType = typeof(String);
col2.ColumnName = "Name";
dt.Columns.Add(col2);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented));
```

OutPut:

```
{
  "Table1": []
}
```

As you can see, once I serialize the DataSet all the column information is lost from my DataTable. Does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: This is a known limitation of Json.NET's DataTable serialization, see [Serializing a DataSet with empty data tables loses all column information #1343](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1343).

Comment: Your options would seem to be 1) Use XML not JSON, since XML preserves schema information; 2) Add an empty column as is suggested in [Serializing a DataSet with empty data tables loses all column information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57553153); 3) Write your own custom converter like the one from [How to include column metadata in JSON for an empty DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33499760) or [this github comment](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1343#issuecomment-308947721).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways is just to add an empty row

```
if (dt.Rows.Count==0) dt.Rows.Add();

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

output

```
{
  "Table1": [
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Name": null
    }
  ]
}
```

or if your ds has several tables

```
    foreach (DataTable t in ds.Tables)
        if (t.Rows.Count==0) t.Rows.Add();
```

if you have a lot of these, you can write a custom converter

```
public class DsJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DataSet>
{
    public override DataSet ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DataSet existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DataSet ds = JObject.Load(reader).ToObject<DataSet>();

        foreach (DataTable t in ds.Tables)
            if (t.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                var isEmptyRow = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < t.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Rows[0][i].ToString())) isEmptyRow = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (isEmptyRow) t.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        return ds;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DataSet value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        foreach (DataTable t in value.Tables)
            if (t.Rows.Count == 0) t.Rows.Add();

        writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this was voted down. Voting up.

Comment: I am very pleased.  Thank you.