# How to correctly serialize an empty DataTable with json.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

I want to serialize a `DataTable` object which has **no rows**, but **it has columns**.

Now Newtonsoft JSON.NET serializes such a DataTable as a **totally empty table, without columns.**

**However, I want the names and the types of the columns!**

How can I configure JSON.NET to serialize an empty DataTable with Column Names and Column Types ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110931/4753489

Comment: Is there no other way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DataTable `dt` then you can *project* the columns into a list of anonymous type (containing ColumnName and Type) using Linq like this:

```
var columns = dt.Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(c => new { Name = c.ColumnName, Type = c.DataType.ToString()});
```

Then using `Newtonsoft.Json` you can serialize like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(columns);
```

Or using `System.Text.Json`:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(columns);
```

Which (if your table has 3 columns - `Id`, `Name`, `Date`) will produce JSON something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Id",
    "Type": "System.Int32"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name",
    "Type": "System.String"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Date",
    "Type": "System.DateTime"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is a great idea, so actually the columns are serialized as a separate list. This might also solve another issue, as all Int32 are converted to Int64 during serialization and de-serialization. I will try it and come back later here.